# How to remove one specific namespace from XML element

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces

I have looked for this specific case, but have not found. I have this XML, that has other elements besides those three, but they are irrelevant. Relevant elements have two namespaces attached to it. I want to remove xmlns:two so in the output only first xmlns is present.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header>
    <one:id xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so" 
        xmlns:two="http://x.com/xsd/woa.xsd">555</one:id>
    <one:protocolVersion xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so" 
        xmlns:two="http://x.com/xsd/woa.xsd">2.0</one:protocolVersion>
    <one:userId xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so" 
        xmlns:two="http://x.com/xsd/woa.xsd">12345</one:userId>
</Header>
```

Now what I want, is to remove xmlns:two

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Header>
    <one:id xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">555</one:id>
    <one:protocolVersion xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">2.0</one:protocolVersion>
    <one:userId xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">12345</one:userId>
</Header>
```

I have tried something like this, but it removes wrong namespace. It removes same namespace that is prefix.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:two="http://x.com/xsd/woa.xsd" 
    xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="one:id">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Note that your XML is not well-formed. You have an opening `<one:id>` tag, but a closing `</xro:id>` tag.

Comment: Thanks @TimC, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of things preventing this from creating the result you've described:

Here you're copying only the namespaces that the element does *not* use rather than the ones that it does:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(. = namespace-uri(..))]"/>
```

Here you're creating an element in the null namespace (no namespace):

```
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
```

You've declared the `one` and `two` namespaces on the XSLT stylesheet's root element, which means they'll be included on the output document's root element.

In order to get the result you've described, you can use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="one:*" xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so" >
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or you can use a more general, namespace-agnostic approach:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these produce the output you've said that you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `xsl:copy-of` expression you want is this, to copy only the namespace that matches the current element

```
<xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[. = namespace-uri(..)]"/>
```

Additionally, you should be creating the element with `name()` and not `local-name()`, otherwise you are creating the element in no namespace, given that you have no default namespace.

However, as you are creating a new element with a prefix that has been declared in the XSLT, I don't think you need to copy the namespaces at all.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="one:*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could also do this....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:one="http://x.com/xsd/so">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="one:*">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: In fact you could just unconditionally do `<xsl:copy-of select="/" copy-namespaces="no"/>` at the top level - this removes all unused namespaces, which might (or might not) meet the requirement. At any rate, it works for this example.